# Cron job question

Tags: cron

I want to run a php script every 10 minutes, between the hours of 9:30AM - 4:00PM

I googled before asking, and didn't have any success.

Anyone know how to do this? Or point me in the right direction?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try the following three lines in crontab

```
0,10,20,30,40,50      10-15                    * * * # Every 10 minutes for the hours 10am - 3pm
0                     16                       * * * # 4pm
30,40,50              9                        * * * # and 9:30, 9:40, 9:50
```

Answer (score 0):

Run it from cron in every 10 minutes, check th date in PHP do nothing if it's outside the range.

```
*/10 * * * * /usr/bin/php  /path/to/your/script.php
```

Comment: You could also limit the hours between 9AM to 4PM, just to cool it down, by `*/10 */9-16 * * *`.